# Simple example of independent events fails to satisfy

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Simplest example is tossing a coin.

- Event A: Tossing a coin results in heads
- Event B: Tossing a coin results in heads again.

These are independent events i.e. A doesn't influence the B.

$A=\{H\}$
$B=\{H\}$

$A∩B=\{H\}$

$P(A) = P(B) = P(A\cap B) = \frac{1}{2}$

So, here clearly,

$P(A)(B) \neq P(A \cap B)$

Am I writing this in wrong way?

Comment: This is not clear.  What are $A,B$?  Are you, for example, tossing a fair coin twice and then $A$ is "the first toss comes up $H$" and  $B$ is "the second toss comes up $H$"?

Comment: Yes, tossing a fair coin twice and A and B are events.

Comment: Are $A$, $B$ the two events I described?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you described!

Comment: If my interpretation is correct then the sample space is $TT, TH, HT, HH$ each with probability $\frac 14$, $A=\{HT, HH\}$ and $B=\{TH, HH\}$ and $A\cap B=\{HH\}$.

Comment: I see. Sample space becomes that with two events, I thought it was just {H, T}. I understood it now, thanks.

Comment: @lulu: How is event A and B contain "HT" and "TH", since I only wanted two heads?

Comment: in my sample space I consider every possible sequence of two coin tosses.  $A$ consists of all the sequences in which the first toss was $H$.  $B$ consists of all the sequences in which the second toss was $H$.

Comment: I see. Why is it necessary to say, event $A = {HT, HH}$ when my 'A' event is just $HH$? Why not also include $TT$ as well.. I am a bit confused how this works. However, I understand that sample space is $HH, TT, HT, TH$ but I don't understand why include $HT$ and $HH$ in event A and $TH$ and $HH$ in event B.

Comment: The event $HH$ consists of throwing Heads twice.  That is not what you said $A$ was.  You said $A$ was just throwing Heads first.  Thus $A$ consists of the two events $HT, HH$ since $A$.  $HH$ is $A\cap B$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Possibly my mistake. I have a coin. I am tossing it up once, it comes as head. I am tossing it up second time, it comes as head. I want to write these events. So, if I say, $A = {H}$ and $B = {H}$ does it make sense? Two tosses = two A and B events.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to write $A=H$ and $B=H$, as that would appear to suggest that $A=B$ which is not true.  As you are talking about two tosses, my event space makes sense.

Comment: Yes, I see now. It seems more like a mathematics problem itself. So, if I had a die instead then I can't say I got even numbers on die twice $A = {2, 4, 6}$ and $B = {2, 4, 6}$. I didn't know this.

Comment: If you want to consider two separate tosses, then your notation must take into account both tosses.  It's not complicated.  If we toss a fair die twice the sample space has $36$ possible outcomes.  It is easy enough, if a bit tedious, to write them all down.  You are free to use short hand like $EO$ to indicate that the first toss is Even and the second Odd,

Comment: I have just one question, it will end my confusion. I have seen problems with die roll example where  $A = {1, 3, 5}$ and $B = {2, 4, 6}$.. Now these A and B are events but does it mean die was rolled once or twice? It doesn't seem like rolled twice because then I would have combination of numbers like $A = {12, 23, 43}$ just as with coin example HH, TT, etc.. So, how a single die roll is creating events A and B?

Comment: Looking at that I would guess that just one roll was involved.  So the problem would be something like "you toss a fair die.  Let $A$ be the event "an odd number came up" and let $B$ be the event "an even number came up"."

Comment: Now, it makes sense why my original question was wrong. Thanks for patience and helping me see the light.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that what you wrote is not correct. Note that $A$ and $B$ are separate events that happen to have the same probability of occurring. Here's how we can proceed
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A\vert B)P(B)$$
Since $A$ and $B$ are independent events, we have
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$$
$$=\frac12\cdot\frac12=\frac14$$
I hope this helps you understand.